# React Native - Different image size between android & iOS

Tags: react-native

I use the same code for android & iOS. However, I found the appearances are different between two platforms, especially the image size (shown as below).

I wanna ask:

1. How can I set a configuration to make two platforms become consistent?
2. How to set android & iOS stylesheet setting on the same code?

Thanks!!

---

```
 <MenuButton onPress={() => this.toggle()} style={styles.menuButton}>
      <Image source={require('../images/menu.png')} style={styles.menuButtonImage}/>
 </MenuButton>
```

[StyleSheet setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8XJF.png)

[Android & iOS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a38nd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed images get rendered differently on the other platform. If I remember correctly it should be enough to set a static size. If you have to tweak the style for each platform I would do the following:

```
# Use a ternary statement in the function that gets your style object:

getImage () {
    const getStyle = () => ({height:(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 36 : 48)})

    # then call it where you set the propery:

    return <Image source={require('../images/menu.png')} style={getStyle()} />
}
```

This way it will get called on each re-render of the parent.

In fact, I have all styles defined like this. It works like a charm for dynamic styles that may be dependent on properties. Also, it's a nice pattern to keep components and functions in components that return elements as self contained as possible.